# no overloaded function could convert all the argument types

Tags: c++, string, c++11, vector

I want to create a function `Vec2()` for the follow input:
`string in="[[">>v","v^<","<><"],[">>v","v^<","<><"]]"`
it should return
`{{">>v","v^<","<><"},{">>v","v^<","<><"}}`

It works fine in single string version,in that case ,`stringToVecStr()`gives the correct answer.
ie: `[">>v","v^<","<><"]`->`{">>v","v^<","<><"}`

But for `Vec2()` it errors out:

```cpp
'std::vector<std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string>>, std::allocator<std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std: :string>>>>::push_back':
  no overloaded function could convert all the argument types temp C:\Users\mingy\source\repos\temp\temp\Source.cpp 72
```

What does this mean and where should I modify it?

Here is a minimal reproducible example：

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<type_traits>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
#include<regex>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;

inline string stringToVecStr(const string input) {
  string result;
  for (int i = 1; i < input.length() - 1; i++) {
    char currentChar = input[i];
    if (input[i] == '\\') {
      char nextChar = input[i + 1];
      switch (nextChar) {
      case '\"': result.push_back('\"'); break;
      case '/': result.push_back('/'); break;
      case '\\': result.push_back('\\'); break;
      case 'b': result.push_back('\b'); break;
      case 'f': result.push_back('\f'); break;
      case 'r': result.push_back('\r'); break;
      case 'n': result.push_back('\n'); break;
      case 't': result.push_back('\t'); break;
      default: break;
      }
      i++;
    }
    else {
      result.push_back(currentChar);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

const int32_t TREE_NODE_BOUNDNARY = INT_MIN + 1; // replace null

//note:Vec() is to hanlde `vector<int>` such as `[1,2,3,4,5]`
//I put it here just for the completeness of the code, you can ignore it
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> Vec(const std::string inputStr)
{
  std::vector<T> ret;
  const std::string pattern = R"(([+|-]?\w*\.?[\w+|#|(|)|\.]),?)";
  std::smatch match;
  std::string log = inputStr;
  while (regex_search(log, match, (std::regex)pattern)) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string treeNull = match.str(1) == "null" ? std::to_string(TREE_NODE_BOUNDNARY) : match.str(1);
    ss << treeNull;
    T temp;
    ss >> temp;
    ret.push_back(temp);
    log = match.suffix();
  }
  if (ret.empty())
    std::cout << "Failed to construct Matrix" << std::endl;
  return ret;
}


template<typename T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> Vec2(const std::string inputStr)
{
  std::vector<std::vector<T>> ret;
  const std::string pattern = R"((\[[^\[\]]*\]))";
  std::smatch match;
  std::string log = inputStr;
  while (regex_search(log, match, (std::regex)pattern)) {
    std::string vec = match.str(1);
    if (is_same_v<T, string>)
    {
      string temp = stringToVecStr(vec);
      ret.push_back(temp);
    }
    else {
      ret.push_back(Vec<T>(vec));
    }
    log = match.suffix();
  }

  if (ret.empty()) {
    std::cout << "Failed to construct Matrix" << std::endl;
  }
  return ret;
}

int main()
{
  std::string in1 = "[\">>v\",\"v^<\",\"<><\"]";
  auto t1 = stringToVecStr(in1);
  cout << t1;
  //cout << endl;

  std::string in2 = "[[\">>v\",\"v^<\",\"<><\"],[\">>v\",\"v^<\",\"<><\"]]";
  auto t2 = Vec2<string>(in2);
  for (auto i : t1)cout << i << " ";
  return 0;
}
```

It says `It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.`, but I really don't have anything to add.

Below is the full output：

```bash
1>------ Build started: Project: temp, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Source.cpp
1>C:\Users\mingy\source\repos\temp\temp\Source.cpp(69,5): warning C4984: 'if constexpr' is a C++17 language extension
1>C:\Users\mingy\source\repos\temp\temp\Source.cpp(72,10): error C2665: 'std::vector<std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>,std::allocator<std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>>>::push_back': no overloaded function could convert all the argument types
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include\vector(939,23): message : could be 'void std::vector<std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>,std::allocator<std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>>>::push_back(_Ty &&)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>
1>        ]
1>C:\Users\mingy\source\repos\temp\temp\Source.cpp(72,10): message : 'void std::vector<std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>,std::allocator<std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>>>::push_back(_Ty &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::string' to '_Ty &&'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>
1>        ]
1>C:\Users\mingy\source\repos\temp\temp\Source.cpp(72,21): message : Reason: cannot convert from 'std::string' to '_Ty'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>
1>        ]
1>C:\Users\mingy\source\repos\temp\temp\Source.cpp(72,21): message : No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include\vector(935,23): message : or       'void std::vector<std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>,std::allocator<std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>>>::push_back(const _Ty &)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>
1>        ]
1>C:\Users\mingy\source\repos\temp\temp\Source.cpp(72,10): message : 'void std::vector<std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>,std::allocator<std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>>>::push_back(const _Ty &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::string' to 'const _Ty &'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>
1>        ]
1>C:\Users\mingy\source\repos\temp\temp\Source.cpp(72,21): message : Reason: cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'const _Ty'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>
1>        ]
1>C:\Users\mingy\source\repos\temp\temp\Source.cpp(72,21): message : No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>C:\Users\mingy\source\repos\temp\temp\Source.cpp(72,10): message : while trying to match the argument list '(std::string)'
1>C:\Users\mingy\source\repos\temp\temp\Source.cpp(94,29): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::vector<std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>,std::allocator<std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>>> Vec2<std::string>(const std::string)' being compiled
1>Done building project "temp.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Thanks for the discussion everyone, I think I have achieved my intent correctly

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<type_traits>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
#include<regex>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;

inline vector<string> VecStr(const string input) {
  if (input.size() < 2) {
    std::cout << "Construct vector<string> failed" << std::endl;
    return{};
  }
  vector<string> res;
  string result;
  for (int i = 1; i < input.length() - 1; i++) {
    char currentChar = input[i];
    if (input[i] == '\\') {
      char nextChar = input[i + 1];
      switch (nextChar) {
      case '\"': result.push_back('\"'); break;
      case '/': result.push_back('/'); break;
      case '\\': result.push_back('\\'); break;
      case 'b': result.push_back('\b'); break;
      case 'f': result.push_back('\f'); break;
      case 'r': result.push_back('\r'); break;
      case 'n': result.push_back('\n'); break;
      case 't': result.push_back('\t'); break;
      default: break;
      }
      i++;
    }
    else {
      result.push_back(currentChar);
    }
    if (input[i] == ',')
    {
      result.pop_back();
      result.pop_back();
      res.push_back(result.substr(1));
      result = "";
    }
  }
  if(!result.empty()){
    result.pop_back();
    res.push_back(result.substr(1));
  }
  return res;
}

const int32_t TREE_NODE_BOUNDNARY = INT_MIN + 1; // replace null

inline std::vector<std::vector<string>> Vec2Str(const std::string inputStr)
{
  std::vector<std::vector<string>> ret;
  const std::string pattern = R"((\[[^\[\]]*\]))";
  std::smatch match;
  std::string log = inputStr;
  while (regex_search(log, match, (std::regex)pattern)) {
    const std::string vec = match.str(1);
    ret.push_back(VecStr(vec));
    log = match.suffix();
  }
  if (ret.empty()) std::cout << "Construct vector<vector<string>> failed" << std::endl;
  return ret;
}

//template for int and long long
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> Vec(const std::string inputStr)
{
  std::vector<T> ret;
  const std::string pattern = R"(([+|-]?\w*\.?[\w+|#|(|)|\.]),?)";
  std::smatch match;
  std::string log = inputStr;
  while (regex_search(log, match, (std::regex)pattern)) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string treeNull = match.str(1) == "null" ? std::to_string(TREE_NODE_BOUNDNARY) : match.str(1);
    ss << treeNull;
    T temp;
    ss >> temp;
    ret.push_back(temp);
    log = match.suffix();
  }
  if (ret.empty())
    std::cout << "Construct Vector failed" << std::endl;
  return ret;
}
template<typename T>
std::vector<std::vector<int>> Vec2(const std::string inputStr)
{
  std::vector<std::vector<T>> ret;
  const std::string pattern = R"((\[[^\[\]]*\]))";
  std::smatch match;
  std::string log = inputStr;
  while (regex_search(log, match, (std::regex)pattern)) {
    const std::string vec = match.str(1);
    ret.push_back(Vec<int>(vec));
    log = match.suffix();
  }
  if (ret.empty()) std::cout << "Construct failed" << std::endl;
  return ret;
}


int main()
{
  std::string in1 = "[\">>v\",\"v^<\",\"<><\"]";
  auto t1 = VecStr(in1);
  for (auto i : t1) cout << i << endl;

  std::string in2 = "[[\">>v\",\"v^<\",\"<><\"],[\">>v\",\"v^<\",\"<><\"]]";
  auto t2 = Vec2Str(in2);
  for (auto i : t2)for(auto j:i)cout << j << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are those two lines the *only* output from the build? If not them please copy-paste the full and complete build log into your question. There might be notes and other information that could help with the error.

Comment: `stringToVecStr` ignores the last character, if the second to last character is not a `'\\'`.

Comment: You need a conditional that is resolved at compile time. `if (is_same_v<T, string>)` —> `if constexpr (is_same_v<T, string>)`.

Comment: @molbdnilo After I changed the `if` to `if constexpr` the error still exists

Comment: @mch No, there is nothing wrong with `stringToVecStr`, you can verify this by commenting the definition of `Vec2` and the call statement for `Vec2<string>`

Comment: Well, `temp` is a `std::string`, `ret` is a `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>`, so what do you expect from `ret.push_back(temp);`?

Comment: @molbdnilo Ah, it was my fault!

Comment: @Kargath no, it ignores the first and last character: https://godbolt.org/z/fnoejW3aY

Comment: Minor point: you don't need the backslash in `'\"'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just eliminated the compile-break , but actual situation changes are depend on your opinion and condition , So you should replace correct change.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
inline string stringToVecStr(const string input) {
  string result;
  for (int i = 1; i < input.length() - 1; i++) {
    char currentChar = input[i];
    if (input[i] == '\\') {
      char nextChar = input[i + 1];
      switch (nextChar) {
        case '\"':
          result.push_back('\"');
          break;
        case '/':
          result.push_back('/');
          break;
        case '\\':
          result.push_back('\\');
          break;
        case 'b':
          result.push_back('\b');
          break;
        case 'f':
          result.push_back('\f');
          break;
        case 'r':
          result.push_back('\r');
          break;
        case 'n':
          result.push_back('\n');
          break;
        case 't':
          result.push_back('\t');
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      i++;
    } else {
      result.push_back(currentChar);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

const int32_t TREE_NODE_BOUNDNARY = INT_MIN + 1;  // replace null

// note:Vec() is to hanlde `vector<int>` such as `[1,2,3,4,5]`
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> Vec(const std::string inputStr) {
  std::vector<T> ret;
  const std::string pattern = R"(([+|-]?\w*\.?[\w+|#|(|)|\.]),?)";
  std::smatch match;
  std::string log = inputStr;
  while (regex_search(log, match, (std::regex)pattern)) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string treeNull = match.str(1) == "null"
                               ? std::to_string(TREE_NODE_BOUNDNARY)
                               : match.str(1);
    ss << treeNull;
    T temp;
    ss >> temp;
    ret.push_back(temp);
    log = match.suffix();
  }
  if (ret.empty()) std::cout << "构造Vector失败" << std::endl;
  return ret;
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> Vec2(
    const std::string &inputStr) {  // change to refrence(prevent copy)
  std::vector<std::vector<T>> ret;
  const std::string pattern = R"((\[[^\[\]]*\]))";
  std::smatch match;
  std::string log = inputStr;
  while (regex_search(log, match, (std::regex)pattern)) {
    std::string vec = match.str(1);
    if (is_same_v<T, string>) {
      string temp = stringToVecStr(vec);
      ret.push_back(std::vector<T>(
          1, temp));  // changed -> std::vector init , but this code
                      // always add one string to vector if you want add
                      // to an item in outer vector , you should have an
                      // condition to add which one element?
    } else {
      ret.push_back(Vec<T>(vec));  // you checked type not be string , but input
                                   // argument in Vec(...) is string . why?
    }
    log = match.suffix();
  }

  if (ret.empty()) {
    std::cout << "Failed to construct Matrix" << std::endl;
  }
  return ret;
}

int main() {
  std::string in1 = "[\">>v\",\"v^<\",\"<><\"]";
  auto t1 = stringToVecStr(in1);
  for (auto i : t1) cout << i;
  cout << endl;

  std::string in2 = "[[\">>v\",\"v^<\",\"<><\"],[\">>v\",\"v^<\",\"<><\"]]";
  auto t2 = Vec2<string>(in2);
  for (auto const &i : t2)  // changed
    for (auto const &j : i) cout << j << " ";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all, what *was* the problem? What have you done to solve the problem? What changes have you made in your code? And you don't really need to copy all of the code, unless you changed it all. And code-only answers are highly discouraged. In short: Just because your answer was accepted doesn't mean it's a good answer. Please read about [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you can read the code and I changed 4-5 line and explained there because it was depend on his opinion paradigm , How read whole of the answer? if you can't read whole of the answer , so don't click on the questions that you didn't ask. 
https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-read-first-time-and-remember-the-long-answers

Comment: _"if you can't read whole of the answer , so don't click on the questions that you didn't ask"_ I guess dudes comment was given while working on [review queues](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reviews-intro). And i agree with him on the code wall; if you changes only a small part, consider posting only that one.